# bx-slider autoHover on pager

Tags: jquery, bxslider

How can i set autoHover on pager ?

I have bx-slider set to :

```
    pager: true,
    autoHover: true,
    autoControlsCombine: true,
```

My pager is in absolute positioned wrapper. I would like same behavior on entering pagger as when i enter slider .

Cant use startAuto/stopAuto functions with mouseenter/leave since they are changing play/stop button, so when i leave pager it will cancel pause i clicked before.

Is there way to simulate mouse enter/leave in same way as autoHover on entering slider itself ?

Comment: stop/startAuto can have parameter, if set on "true" stop/play button is not affected. What is just what i needed to gain .
    $(".homepagerselector").mouseenter(function(){
        homepagemainslider.stopAuto(true);
    });
    $(".homepagerselector").mouseleave(function(){
        homepagemainslider.startAuto(true);
    });

Comment: EDITED - This does not work it will bug play/stop button causing it will freez at play css state so will be not possible to start/stop through control again .